# Why does this rsync command change the user correctly, but not the group?

Tags: command-line, rsync, chown

I have a directory on my local machine called `foo` that contains a file called `document`. The user and group for `foo` and `document` are `A:B`.

I want to move these files to a remote directory `remote-dir` using rsync. `remote-dir` contains other directories, but not `/foo`, so rsync will be introducing `/foo` and `/foo/document` to the remote directory for the first time. The files inside `remote-dir` should all have a user:group of `J:L`. Here's what that looks like:

**BEFORE**

```
/foo/         (A:B)        /remote-dir/      (J:K)
 `- document  (A:B)         `- other/        (J:L)
                            `- directories/  (J:L)
```

I used the following rsync command to carry out the transfer*:

```
rsync -rv --super --owner --chown=J:L ./foo/ root@remote:/remote-dir/foo
```

**EXPECTED**

```
/foo/         (A:B)        /remote-dir/      (J:K)
 `- document  (A:B)         `- other/        (J:L)
                            `- directories/  (J:L)
                            `- foo/          (J:L)
                               `- document   (J:L)
```

I expect `/foo` and `/foo/document` to appear in `remote-dir` with a user:group of `J:L`.

**ACTUAL**

```
/foo/         (A:B)        /remote-dir/      (J:K)
 `- document  (A:B)         `- other/        (J:L)
                            `- directories/  (J:L)
                            `- foo/          (J:root)
                               `- document   (J:root)
```

In actuality, `/foo` and `/foo/document` appear in `remote-dir` with a user-group of `J:root`, `root` being the group of the root user I specified in the rsync command (`root@remote:[...]`).

According to the man page, `--chown=J:L` is equivalent to `--usermap=*:J --groupmap=*:L`, and as we can see, the usermap is working correctly, but the groupmap is not.

Am I doing anything wrong? Any incorrect assumptions? **What should be on my sanity checklist?**

*rsync options explained:

- `-r` for recursive
- `--super` because the "receiver attempts super-user activities" (chown)
- `--owner` because chown uses `--usermap` and `--groupmap` internally, and these options require `--owner` to function (**edit:** actually, this is incorrect. `--usermap` requires `--owner`, but `--groupmap` requires a separate option `--group`.)

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic (belongs on [SU]), but +1 for a clear question that shows research  effort.

Comment: Oh gosh, in my daze of confusion regarding this issue, I forgot to consider which SE community I should post this to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rsync man page has the answer.

I was aware of this first part:

> For the --usermap option to have any effect, the -o (--owner) option must be used (or implied), and the receiver will need to be running as a super-user (see also the --fake-super  option).

But I didn't realize I also needed -g (--groupmaps):

> **For the --groupmap option to have any effect**, **the -g (--groups) option must be used** (or implied), and the receiver will need to have permissions to set that group.